# Cannot understand some C code about FIlter

Tags: c, signal-processing

When I try to practice a project about using ADC module to read current 3 phase, I meet some code sentence about Filter ADC offset signal but I don't know what the filter is. My code below:

```c
//Offset filter coefficient K1: 0.05/(T+0.05);
float32 K1 = 0.998;  
//Offset filter coefficient K2: T/(T+0.05);                   
float32 K2 = 0.001999;                  

//Ph.A current offset
offsetIA = K1 * offsetIA + K2 * AdcResult.ADCRESULT1;
//Ph.B current offset   
offsetIB = K1 * offsetIB + K2 * AdcResult.ADCRESULT2;
//Ph.C current offset   
offsetIC = K1 * offsetIC + K2 * AdcResult.ADCRESULT3;
```

Please help me determine the type of filter.

Comment: It looks like s simple low pass recursive IIR filter (single pole). Note that K1+K2==1. You might want to read a little up on basic DSP and digital filters.

Comment: Indeed a low pass IIR filter of the form `y[n] = K1*y[n-1] + K2*x[n]`. i'm not a specialist but it looks like the cutoff frequency is very low.

Comment: `K2` would be better initialized as `K2 = 1.0f - K1;`